# sqlpackage.exe really slow to deploy a small database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, data-tier-applications

I use VS2015 to build my database project in release mode and then copy the generated .dacpac file to my production server.

I am then running a command as follows:

```
sqlpackage.exe /action:publish /targetconnectionstring:"Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=NorthwindDb" /sourcefile:"c:\temp\NorthwindDb.dacpac" /p:CreateNewDatabase=false
```

The dacpac size is around 8kb. It contains maybe 10 tables and some static data.

Then I run the command, it takes a really long time to run. Both for creating the initial database and for any upgrades. I estimate for this small database, running the above command takes around 5 minutes.

Is there a way I can improve the speed of this at all?

Certainly during the intial roll out of my application where I will be making small changes and deploying, this time delay will become a real hindrance.

Comment: Why? Why use this method at all? Surely the existing method to install SQL Server is plenty good enough.

Comment: @clifton_h this isn't about installing SQL Server. It is about publishing a database project.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of SqlPackage.exe? It's available here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54106

    Also, what other objects are in your database project?  Are there any SQLCLR assemblies, by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

When I finished my deployment pipeline and started running SqlPackage as part of my AWS Code Deploy scripts it (for some reason) runs a lot faster.

This must be something to do with running it on the command prompt however that is at this time unexplained.